# Adding custom attributes to users on Realm Mobile Platform

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

Is it possible to add custom attributes to a user on the Realm Mobile Platform when registering? (e.g. email address.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@gerbil, at this moment it's not. But it's close to being added!

Comment: It's there a GitHub issue on that?